# How to modify the constraint created by constraintsWithVisualFormat?

Tags: ios, autolayout

for example : I had create constraints using constraintsWithVisualFormat

```
[v1 addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v2(10)]|"
      options:0 metrics:nil views:vs]];
```

but when I decide to change V1's height to V:|[v2(10)]-100-|,because constraintsWithVisualFormat  returns a array of constraints , and I don't know which constraint of the array is the one I have to modify ,how should i do this ?not using constraintsWithVisualFormat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to constraints array.

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v2(10)]|"
  options:0 metrics:nil views:vs];
[v1 addConstraints:constraints];
[v1 removeConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v2(10)]-100-|"
  options:0 metrics:nil views:vs];
[v1 addConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: Ok, you means recreate the constraints and add them again , what i was doing is choose to use addconstraint for the constraint will be changed~~both not looks nice-_-

Comment: Ok. From 
`constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` documentation: _The constraints are returned in the same order they were specified in the visual format string._ So you can access the single constraint by index and change it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful for you

```
NSArray * arrConstarint= v1.constraints;
    for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in arrConstarint)
    {
        if (constraint.firstAttribute==NSLayoutAttributeHeight && constraint.firstItem == v1)
        {
            // change height of view
            // if not find proper constraint then add constraint.secondAttribute etc in condition
            constraint.constant=100;//set your height
        }
    }
```

Not required reference to constraints array.
but you have a reference of view which view change constraints.